# how to open a pdf from sdcard and display in fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, android-fragments, android-activity

I am implementing a tablet application which at left side shows list of my pdf files and on the right side I want to show the pdf file data. How can I do that? and I want  to open  Pdf in fragment. 
**Requirements:** 
 1. Should load PDF from local file.
 2. Must be able to open PDF using Fragments in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some library like [android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) to display PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/yourfolder";
File file = new File(path,"file.pdf");
```

Add this lines in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Add this lines in your Manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use android [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) if your android min support version is api level 21